# Why do i keep getting a WinError 10061 on my client server. This never used to happen

Tags: python, windows, server

[ERRO CODE JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvrC8.png)
**[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

I keep getting this error and have no clue why. This never used to happen but when I tried opening the program today, this happens.

```
import socket
import threading

#choosing nickname
nickname = input("Choose your nickname:\n  ")

#connecting to server
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 55555))

#listening to server and sending nickname
def recieve():
    while True:
        try:
            #recieve message from server
            #if 'NICK' send nickname
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            if message == 'NICK':
                client.send(nickname.encode('ascii'))
            else:
                print(message)
        except:
            #close connection when error
            print("An ERROR occured!")
            client.close()
            break

#sending messages to server
def write():
    while True:
        message = '{}: {}'.format(nickname, input(''))
        client.send(message.encode('ascii'))

#starting threads for listening and writing
receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=recieve)
receive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

Comment: Your server is either not accessible over your network, or isn’t running on the port you expect. As presumably your code normally works then clearly this is most likely a problem in your environment - nothing anyone on StackOverflow can help you with. And anyway  read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Well, what changes were made between the last time it worked and now? any settings change on the server?

Comment: Are you sure you are referring to the correct IP? 127.0.0.1 is set to your local computer. Is the server and client on the same computer?

Comment: @user1558604 i have changed the ip to the server ip but still getting the same error, also no changes have been made that i am aware of